# Access PHP array element

Tags: php, arrays

I struggle to access specific item within my PHP array, which is created like this `array('expected' => array('form', 'title'))`

```
.Array
(
    [expected] => Array
        (
            [0] => form
            [1] => title
        )

)
```

I would like to access the title of the first array (*expected*) as well as the value of the element within this array (*form* and *title*)
I tried methods such as `array_values()`or `key` but I never get the right results.

**EDIT**
Thanks to Aamir, this problem is solved. 
In fact, it was because I pass the array as a parameter into a method and I set it to null by default. Yes I know, dumb stuff.

Comment: what should be the output you want?

Comment: I just want to access the element I cited. Fro instance, print "expected", "form" and "title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
 echo $key; //expected
 echo $value[0]; //form
 echo $value[1]; //title

 //OR if you have more values then 
foreach ($value as $key1 => value1){
  echo $value1; //form in 1st iteration and title in 2nd iteration
 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is vague enough to be answered by: Use a [RecursiveTreeIterator](http://docs.php.net/RecursiveTreeIterator)

```
<?php
$x = array(
    'level1' => array(
        'item1.1',
        'level2'=>array(
            'item2.1',
            'item2.2',
            'level3'=>array(
                'item3.1'
            )
        ),
        'item1.2'
    )
);

$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator($x), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
foreach($it as $line) {
    echo $line, PHP_EOL;
}
```

prints

```
\-Array
  |-item1.1
  |-Array
  | |-item2.1
  | |-item2.2
  | \-Array
  |   \-item3.1
  \-item1.2
```

You might want to refine your question....

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
   $array = array('expected' => array
        (
            0 => 'form',
        1 => 'title',
        )

);
$expected= $array['expected'];
$form = $expected[0];
$title = $expected[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
$my_array = Array
(
    'expected' => Array
        (
            '0' => 'form',
            '1' => 'title'
        )

);

echo $form =  $my_array[key($my_array)][0];  // print form 
echo $title = $my_array[key($my_array)][1];  //print title
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I do not know what the key of the Array (here "expected") will be, therefore I cannot use it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$array = array('expected' => array('form', 'title'));
function  testFunc($array)
{

  foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {

      if(is_string($key))
      {
          echo $key."<br>";
      }

       if(is_string($value))
      {
          echo $value."<br>";
      }
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        testFunc($value);
    }

}  
}
testFunc($array);
?>
```

output:

```
expected
form
title
```