# How to get json data in blade laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, view, laravel-blade

In the blade template:

```
<?php
      $meta = json_encode($datas,true);   
      echo $meta;
?>
```

It shows:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"title":"Alice.","rating":0},
{"id":2,"title":"So Alice.","rating":2},
{"id":3,"title":"Alice.","rating":2},
{"id":4,"title":"After a.","rating":2},
{"id":5,"title":"Alice.","rating":0}],
"meta":{"song_count":5}}
```

My question is how to get (song_count: 5 ) in blade template.
I have tried :
echo $meta['meta'];

"
it shows;

```
"Illegal string offset 'meta'"
```

Anyone can help, thank you so much

Comment: Why did you encode the `$data`? You can get it from the data array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access PHP array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649841/access-php-array-element)

Comment: `var_dump(data);` to see is that the array or the object. Then access those elements/members accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` method give you a **json** formatted data. You need to decode it :

```php
$meta = json_encode($datas,true);   
$meta = json_decode($meta, true);
echo $meta;
```

Now you access the array property as  `$meta['meta'];`

NB : if `$datas` is already an array, then you don't need to encode and decode it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and help, when I use "echo $meta['meta'];" it shows empty, as you see the meta has some data.

Comment: what is the output of `dd($datas);`?

Comment: SongsCollection {#198 ▼
  +collects: null
  +collection: Collection {#208 ▼
    #items: array:5 [▶]
  }
  +resource: LengthAwarePaginator {#204 ▶}
  +with: []
  +additional: array:1 [▼
    "meta" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
}

Comment: "meta":{"song_count":5} is under "+resource", I need to access the meta in resource.

Comment: would you please share the screenshot of the output `dd($datas);`

Comment: Here is the dd($datas) : https://snipboard.io/8uPEAm.jpg

Comment: Here is the dd($datas) : snipboard.io/8uPEAm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

thats mean you try to take meta key from string because $meta is json not array so you dont need to json_encode $data , you can do direct :-
$datas['meta']['song_count'] if $data is array . but this maybe give you error if $datas is empty to solve this you can make check if $data !empty or use optional method in laravel like this :- optional($datas['meta'])['song_count'] it solve the problem .

Comment: Thank you Mohamed, it shows empty :$datas['meta']['song_count'].

Comment: what is the result of using :- dd($datas, $datas['meta']) ??

Answer (score 0):

The steps to show the value of json data from controller as bwlow:

```
<?php
$datas = json_encode($datas,true);
 //dd($data);
$datas = json_decode($datas);
// dd($datas);
foreach($datas->meta as $link){
 echo $link;
}
?>
```