# How to use the first/only value from this PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

When using `var_dump($myFunction);` it returns the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#33 (1) { ["set_limit"]=> string(7) "3400.00" } }
```

I want to echo the value 3400.00.

I've tried:

```
echo $myFunction[0]; //Displays nothing
echo $myFunction[0]["set_limit"]; //Displays nothing
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Know the difference between an array and an object. You can't access object properties without `->` unless your class implements `ArrayAccess`. Just get the first element and access `set_limit` via `->`. You can also use `current` for this. See https://3v4l.org/MlJCt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access PHP array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649841/access-php-array-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value of your array is an object, which you cannot use as an array. "set_limit" is a property of that object. So you would use

```
echo $myFunction[0]->set_limit;
```

to echo the value of that property.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. It worked perfectly!!